# Bing Web Search API -Snippet result is not correct

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, bing-search

We are taking one string from the article link mentioned below:

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389   (Cannot mention complete link)

A same String we are passing to both Bing As well as Google Search Engine.

String passed:

Summary of bacterial groups found to be altered and factors known to be associated with microbial dysbiosis in asthma subjects is given in Figure 1 . In spite of the relatively large body of epidemiologic literature on the association of microbiome and asthma, the evidence over- all remains inconclusive ( 19 ).

From this this, we are getting same URL result from Bing and Google, but the problem is with the snippet. The snippet which Bing is picking up is very different from the actual snippet it should be. While Google is giving the exact and correct snippet result.

Snippet result of Bing:

Human microbiome research in the past decade has been the field of increasingly intense research much due to its demonstrated impact upon various health conditions including human chronic airway diseases such as asthma and COPD. Many confounding factors have been revealed to play a role in shaping the microbiome in chronic airway diseases. Asthma and COPD follows a typical pattern of …

Snippet Result of Google:

Summary of bacterial groups found to be altered and factors known to be associated with microbial dysbiosis in asthma subjects is given in Figure Figure11. ... In spite of the relatively large body of epidemiologic literature on ... the evidence overall remains inconclusive (19).

Also the bold words in Google are exactly the same as expected while in Bing are altogether different.
Why is that os and should be done to get correct snippet from Bing result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for being a Bing API consumer and providing the valuable feedback. We have fixed this issue and the changes are now reflecting in the Bing APIs and https://www.bing.com.